# mktextfm ptmr8t errors

Tags: fonts, pdftex, build-system, cygwin

Switching environments (to a machine with Cygwin), I got errors like this from pdflatex:

```
kpathsea: Running mktextfm ptmr8t
/usr/share/texmf-dist/web2c/mktexnam: Could not map source abbreviation  for ptmr8t.
/usr/share/texmf-dist/web2c/mktexnam: Need to update ?
mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ptmr8t
This is METAFONT, Version 2.718281 (TeX Live 2013/Cygwin)


kpathsea: Running mktexmf ptmr8t
! I can't find file `ptmr8t'.
<*> ...:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ptmr8t

Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<*> ...:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ptmr8t

Transcript written on mfput.log.
grep: ptmr8t.log: No such file or directory
mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ptmr8t' failed to make ptmr8t.tfm.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.

! Font T1/ptm/m/n/12=ptmr8t at 12.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found
.
<to be read again>
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It means you have a missing font (`! Font T1/ptm/m/n/12=ptmr8t at 12.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found`).

According to [this site](http://www.vidarholen.net/contents/linuxtips/), the package for Ubuntu is `texlive-fonts-recommended`. For Cygwin, the package is `texlive-collection-fontsrecommended` (use the standard [Cygwin installer](http://cygwin.com/install.html)).

Comment: Fixed it for cygwin too.

Comment: for those using nixpkgs under nix shell, the attribute is `collection-fontsrecommended` under `texlive`

Answer (score 8):

For people using BasicTeX, run:

```
sudo tlmgr install collection-fontsrecommended
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had this error with CentOS7.9:

```
kpathsea: Running mktexmf cmr10
! I can't find file `cmr10'.
```

Solution: the packages has similar name:

```
yum install texlive-collection-fontsrecommended
```